# Unable to install Varnish 3 on Centos 7

Tags: centos, redhat, varnish, yum

Varnish 3 package is in the repo /etc/yum.repos.d/varnish.repo
When I do `yum --enablerepo=varnish install varnish`. It says repo doesn't exist.

```
[root@VR1gb yum.repos.d]# rpm -qf varnish.repo 
varnish-release-3.0-1.el6.noarch

[root@VR1gb yum.repos.d]# yum --enablerepo=varnish-3.0 install varnish
It prompts to install Varnish 4 again if I do that. Same thing as I do.
[root@VR1gb yum.repos.d]# yum install varnish
```

Instruction on Varnish page clearly doesn't work.
https://www.varnish-cache.org/installation/redhat

Within varnish.repo

```
[root@VR1gb yum.repos.d]# cat varnish.repo 
[varnish-3.0]
name=Varnish 3.0 for Enterprise Linux el6 - $basearch
baseurl=http://repo.varnish-cache.org/redhat/varnish-3.0/el6/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
#gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-VARNISH
```

yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=varnish-3.0 install varnish

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package varnish.x86_64 0:3.0.6-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: varnish-libs = 3.0.6-1.el6 for package: varnish-3.0.6-1.el6.    x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: varnish-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: varnish-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64 (varnish-3.0)
           Requires: varnish-libs = 3.0.6-1.el6
           Installed: varnish-libs-4.0.2-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               varnish-libs = 4.0.2-1.el7
           Available: varnish-libs-3.0.3-0.rc1.el6.x86_64 (varnish-3.0)
               varnish-libs = 3.0.3-0.rc1.el6
           Available: varnish-libs-3.0.3-1.el6.x86_64 (varnish-3.0)
               varnish-libs = 3.0.3-1.el6
           Available: varnish-libs-3.0.4-1.el6.x86_64 (varnish-3.0)
               varnish-libs = 3.0.4-1.el6
           Available: varnish-libs-3.0.5-1.el6.x86_64 (varnish-3.0)
               varnish-libs = 3.0.5-1.el6
           Available: varnish-libs-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64 (varnish-3.0)
               varnish-libs = 3.0.6-1.el6
Error: Package: varnish-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64 (varnish-3.0)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

[root@VR1gb yum.repos.d]# rpm -qa '*varnish*'

```
varnish-release-3.0-1.el6.noarch
```

[root@VR1gb yum.repos.d]# service varnish start

```
Starting varnish (via systemctl):
```

Comment: What are the contents of the `varnish.repo` file?

Comment: I added to the original post. Thanks

Comment: The name of the repo is `varnish-3.0` but it is enabled by default so you don't need `--enablerepo=varnish-3.0` (unless that disables other repos on CentOS 7). What does the output from `yum install varnish` look like? Do you have any other repos with varnish in them enabled? Does `yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=varnish-3.0 install varnish` give different output?

Comment: yum install varnish, prompts for Varnish 4 install which I know isn't compatible. Post updated.

Comment: You have `varnish-libs-4.0.2` installed from EPEL already `Installed: varnish-libs-4.0.2-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)`. Remove it if you don't want it.

Comment: Yup, I saw that and just removed it. How do I install Varnish 3? Its strange that after varnish 4 being removed from yum. When I do service varnish status, Im still getting some varnish info.

Comment: Issue may be its requiring: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)?

Comment: There may be other packages still installed. What does `rpm -qa '*varnish*'` say? Also not all packages are well packaged and stop themselves on removal.

Comment: I think the issue is that Varnish 3 may not be compatible with Centos 7. Since varnish 3 is in EL6 packages

Comment: It might not be. It certainly isn't a good idea to try to get el6 packages installed on el7.

Comment: There is an el7 repo up on their site though: http://repo.varnish-cache.org/redhat/varnish-3.0/el7/ . But they don't seem to have a `varnish-release` package for it. You could try sticking that in the `varnish.repo` file perhaps.

Comment: yup that worked. however, Im getting issue to start restart varnish service.

Comment: I'd probably say close this question and start a new one if you want help with that issue.

Comment: Cool. If you want to post an answer, I will select it as answer. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: I'm not even sure what to post as an answer. That's why I suggested closing/deleting it. The path from question to solution was round-about given where the question started.

Comment: Ok. I opened a new question. Looks like daemon file is not found upon installation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116560/unable-to-start-varnish-3-service-on-centos-7